# how to get the same id in firebase auth and firebase - real time database?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

How do I get same id for firebase auth and firebase realtime database?
When user register their account, they will get their id in the database, but then I realized that the Id is different? how to make sure I have the same Id for both database?
[Different Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHIb1.png)

```
//create customer
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    authData = firebaseAuth.getUid();
                    String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();
                    Customer info = new Customer(id, name, email, address, telephone_number);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer")
                            .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
                            .setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            regProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Registration Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer")
                                            .child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid())
```

I've tried replace the coding above with this

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer")
                                            .child(id)
```

[image: same id where i want to achieve]

I got the same id but then i encounter another problem where my profile activity cannot be displayed

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String com.example.gerobokgo.Model.Customer.name' on a null object reference

so i decided to change the first coding back.

Comment: Welcome! Is there a reason you're doing `String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();` instead of just using the UID of the user?

Comment: because i want to put the id of the customer. then i will use the id to retrieve or delete the user by calling their getId(). If i don't insert the id then i cannot use the getId() function in my model.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can completely substitute your custom-made id with the UID of Firebase Authentication. No? You would still be able to call your getId(), and the value returned would be the UID.

Comment: Your database would look like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmTFc.png

Comment: I solved this already with my own method. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I solved this problem already

Just have to remove the `String id = databaseReference.push().getKey();`
and change `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Customer").child(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid()).setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()`

to

```
databaseReference.child(authData).setValue(info).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
```

that's it!